# Expected CDF's for bulbs

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

If bulbs fail at a time $T$ randomly in time, where they are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda \gt 0$. A room is lit with two bulbs with two bulbs with parameters $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. How would I find the random variable that records the time at which the room becomes dark.

So far with one bulb I have $E(\lambda_1)=\frac{1}{\lambda_1}$ then similar for $E(\lambda_2)=\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$ , then since they are independent then the intersection (so the room going dark) is: $\frac{1}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}$

Is this the correct way of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way of thinking. Let $X_1$ be a random variable denoting the time at which the first lightbulb fails, and let $X_2$ be a random variable denoting the time at which the second lightbulb fails. Under this notation, the time at which the room becomes dark is given by $\max(X_1, X_2)$. This is true because the room will be lit so long as one lightbulb is still working. So, you want to compute $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_1, X_2)]$.

There is a clever way to do this. Note that we can write

$$\mathbb{E}[X_1 + X_2] = \mathbb{E}[\max(X_{1}, X_{1}) + \min(X_{1}, X_{2})]. $$

We can rearrange and use linearity to find $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_{1}, X_{2})] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] + \mathbb{E}[X_{2}] - \mathbb{E}[\min(X_{1}, X_{2})]$. Also, we know that $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}] + \mathbb{E}[X_{2}]$ is just $\frac{1}{\lambda_1} + \frac{1}{\lambda_2}$.

All that remains is for us to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\min(X_1, X_2)]$. This can be done by noting that

$$F_{\min(X_{1}, X_{2})}(t) = P(\min(X_{1}, X_{2}) \leq t) = P(X_{1} \leq t, X_{2} \leq t) = P(X_{1} \leq t)P(X_{2} \leq t) = \lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t}.$$

In other words, the random variable $\min(X_1, X_2)$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$. This means that $\mathbb{E}[\min(X_{1}, X_{2})] = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$, from which we conclude that the expected time until the room is dark is given by

$$\boxed{\mathbb{E}[\max(X_{1}, X_{2})] = \frac{1}{\lambda_1} + \frac{1}{\lambda_2} - \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}}$$

Comment: This seems very clever, but I shouldn't know how to do this! I am meant to use CDFs?

Comment: I found the CDF of $\min(X_{1}, X_{2})$ in order to compute $\mathbb{E}[\min(X_{1}, X_{2})]$. This allowed me to compute $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_{1}, X_{2})]$ due to how we could rewrite $\mathbb{E}[X_{1} + X_{2}]$. You can alternatively work with the CDF of $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_{1}, X_{2})]$, but that way is much more messier. Surprisingly, finding the expectation of the minimum of exponentially distributed random variables is easier than finding the expectation of the maximum of exponentially distributed random variables.

Comment: Oh I see thank you!

Comment: If I were to do this with 3 variables, then would it be like the inclusion principal: So $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_3}-\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}-\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_3}-\frac{1}{\lambda_2+\lambda_3}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}$

Comment: I have not done the calculation, but I think that you have the right idea. Also, I think you can try to use the $n = 2$ result and rewrite $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3})]$ as $\mathbb{E}[\max(\max(X_{1}, X_{2}), X_{3})]$